# C# Update Database for every Item in listBox

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I have created a Database that has an ID column (aitisi_ID) and a category column(kat_aitisis). I want to Update the kat_aitisis column for every ID that shows up on my listBox with the string `kat1`.

Edit 2: the column 'aitisi_ID' is `int`

I have this so far,but it doesnt work (cn is my SqlConnection and cmd is SqlCommand):

```
// Edit: This is the code that I use to add Items to my listBox
private void loadlist()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        cn.Open();
        string kat = "Εγκυρη";
        cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT aitisi_ID,moria FROM Table2 WHERE kat_aitisis='"+kat+"' ORDER BY moria DESC");
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
    }


string kat1 = "aaaaa";

        cn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Table2 SET kat_aitisis='"+kat1+"' WHERE aitisi_ID='"+listBox1.SelectedIndex+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();

        }  
        cn.Close();
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  What error are you receiving?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors,but the database is not updated

Comment: Is the column `aitisi_ID` numeric?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: I just rejected a whole bunch of edit suggestions which do nothing more than remove 'Please help'-like comments; while your intention is obviously good, these are rejected with the reason of `This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.` ... Please do edit posts! But also make sure they *really* contribute something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the column 'aitisi_ID' is of numeric type the correct update query is

```
    string kat1 = "aaaaa";
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Table2 SET kat_aitisis=@kat WHERE aitisi_ID=@id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kat", kat1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
    cn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }  
    cn.Close();
```

Created a parameterized query with two params and set with initial values.
One parameter of type string with an invarian value (kat1) 
The second parameter is of integer type with a dummy initial value.
Then, in the loop only the varying parameter (@id) will be updated.
The value for the second parameter is taken from the Item collection of ListBox1 that is filled with integers (all the items are passed to the update value) and converted back to int as expected by the datatable

Comment: Yes, in your original query you put the value for the column between single quotes treating it as a string. With a parameter of integer type the value is passed as an integer not as a string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the Id in a single quote block.  Since it is an integer, SQL server will be happy with WHERE aitisi_ID='"+listBox1.SelectedIndex+"', but you do need to ToString() it.

```
WHERE aitisi_ID="+listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()+"
```

Comment: The most appropriate way would be to use a parametrized query.

Answer (score 0):

Also try creating code less general, with a `foreach`:

```
    foreach(object i in listBox1.Items)
```

You don't need single quotes for integers, just for strings.
Try to post your error, debug result, try to put breakpoints and give more info please.

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors,but the database is not updated. Is there a difference between foreach and for?

Comment: with the for you have to go into the array and access it, with foreach you have in the object or var the actual element you want to add.
Open the database, create a query exactly the same as the one you are calling from the code, try to execute it, see what happens: if you can and is added, the problem is the code, if you cant, the problem is the syntax in the query

Comment: and then how do I set the listBox1.SetSelected?

Comment: each item has an id, text... so you can set selected that item by that id: listBox1.SetSelected(object.id, true);

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'id'. I get the same for .text

Comment: each item just has an string value. You can obtain it with i.ToString(). For the set Selected, make an int before the foreach: int j = 0 and at the end of the foreach j++; and at the begining of the foreach put your listBox1.SetSelected(j, true);